# Finding the emission factor for vehicular energy generation

Tags: environmental-protection, fossil-fuel

I hope this is the right venue for my question.
I'm trying to find the conversion factor between vehicular CO2 emissions (in units of mass, e.g. in metric tons) and the energy generated (in kWh).

If I understand correctly I found an emission factor for electricity on EPA's [site](https://www.epa.gov/energy/greenhouse-gases-equivalencies-calculator-calculations-and-references)    - 7.44 × 10^-4 metric tons CO2/kWh.

I assume that the energy efficiency of an average car is different from that of the average power plant, so this will probably not be very useful to estimate the emission factor of vehicles.

I would greatly appreciate a source that could provide this conversion factor.

Many thanks!

Comment: If, in a week or so, you do not get answers here, try [Opendata.se].

Comment: This is going to be vehicle-type dependent and age dependent.  Could you give an example of the "average" car you are considering?

Comment: This should help: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0360128516300442  it has a good table that I think has what you are looking for.  Also refer to https://www.eesi.org/papers/view/fact-sheet-vehicle-efficiency-and-emissions-standards

Comment: Farrenthorpe - let's assume an average American (that is, U.S.) private 5-seater car suitable for urban and semi-urban environments (that is, not an SUV and the like).

Thanks for the article, its a very good starting point.